# Node aggregate using $scope variables

Tags: angularjs, node.js, date, aggregate

Lets say I had 2 $scope variables ($scope.date1, $scope.date2) in my AngularJS code that held dates. In my node aggregate, how would I access those variables to set the date instead of manually setting them? I tried res.body.date1 but couldn't get it working.

```
.aggregate([
  {$match: {"messages.timestamp": {$gte: ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00.0Z")}}},
  {$group : {_id : "$status", number : {$sum : 1}}}
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `req.body.date1` and `req.body.date2`